# Graph API returns the same group multiple times when doing initial delta sync

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In our Azure AD directory one of our groups has 6 members. When calling the `/groups/delta` endpoint without a `syncToken` the result set includes the aforementioned group twice. Once on the first page with 2 members, another time on the second page with 4 members. Together the memberships match the expected ones.

Is this an expected behavior and we should aggregate on our side, or is it a bug?

I had some intermittent issues with the same group being returned multiple times just after modification, however in this case the issue happens every time on our tenant. Since the issue started occurring no changes to directory data were done on the tenant.

Group data on page 1:

```
{
  "description": null,
  "displayName": "crowd-administrators",
  "id": "a6eba1a3-e348-4881-842a-53c1809c10cc",
  "members@delta": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
      "id": "daec3933-f1d1-46f7-b1cb-c99790fa2bf5"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
      "id": "7d58fe5f-a832-4548-98e9-5e7250333ac1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Group data on page 2:

```
{
  "description": null,
  "displayName": "crowd-administrators",
  "id": "a6eba1a3-e348-4881-842a-53c1809c10cc",
  "members@delta": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
      "id": "d23f7435-70ac-40a9-9bed-c57b5af4915d"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
      "id": "4c33e6dc-8efe-4a9b-b6d2-37fef878b6a8"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
      "id": "b051725a-69f8-4bb7-b8f4-14548f16afa1"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
      "id": "84a66ed7-8559-4fb7-963c-150032e4134e"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the directory there's only one group with the name crowd-administrators and it has 6 members in total (the same ones as in the output from page 1 and page 2 combined)

Comment: Could you provide the GET request you're making to `groups/delta`? It would also be helpful to see the JSON output for both variants of the group in question.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT - sure! I'm doing a request to groups/delta with a $select of  `displayName,members,description,id`. There's no deltaToken as it's the initial synchronisation. I updated the question with the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your second page is a response from MSGraph Delta Query when you use the nextLink obtained from first response ... Let me know if it is not correct ...

Group appearing more than once with separate members across multiple pages is technically possible ... Page Split happens due to many factors for example TimeCutOff in processing request, Number of objects in the response, Number of links in the response etc. ...

Comment: You're right! As I mentioned one result is on the first page, the other is on the second. Together the data from both groups form what is actually in the directory - a group with six members. I wasn't sure if the behavior is expected and we should aggregate on our side, or if it's a bug.

 If it's technically possible, then the suggested approach would be to aggregate such groups, right?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes the behavior is expected per design and Client should aggregate the results ...